# Отправить строку как параметры

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть строка `var string = '"name":"John","lastname":"Smith"'`

Пытаюсь отправить

```
$.post("/clients/ajax.php", {"age":"28",
            string
    }, function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
  return false;

});
```

Не получается. Если отправить без 'string', то все нормально отправляется. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: потому что вы задаете объект, но передаете туда почему-то данные без ключей.

Comment: Этот вариант вообще не подходит. Или как можно распарсить эту сроку на ajax.php. Это значение передастся как одна строка.
Я планировал использовать данные $_POST['name'] и $_POST['lastname']
___

Желательно не использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: При отправке данных

    var obj = {"name":"John","lastname":"Smith"};

    $.post("/clients/ajax.php", {
        "age":"28",
        "dataJson": obj,
    }

При принятии данных

    $array = json_decode($_POST['dataJson']);
    echo $array->name;

Comment: @Виталий Дмитриев, давайте сначала узнаем, откуда эти данные приходят в такой странной форме.

> Этот вариант вообще не подходит.

Я вполне себе ответил на заданный вопрос, между тем.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Буду копать в сторону 'json_decode'

Как раз его разбирал сейчас.